# Script does not iterate over multiple email address arguments

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, syntax

I have a simple bash script that will create a YAML formatted template when an email address is passed to the script. I've been trying to have the script iterate over multiple email addresses passed as arguments, but I can only ever get 1 address returned properly.

I have tried using a `for` loop and passing arguments to $1 as $@.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#set -x

# Fetch SSH keys from mounted NAS and generate users.sls templates
onboards=("$*")
ssh_keys_file='ssh_keys.txt'

function usage() {
    echo "Usage: $0 Rick.James@domain.com" >&2
    exit
}

# mount NAS
nas_volume='PATRIOT'
function mountnas() {
sudo mkdir -p "/Volumes/$nas_volume" && sudo chown -R "$(whoami):staff" "/Volumes/$nas_volume"
mount_afp -o automounted "afp://staff:PASSWORD@domain.com/$nas_volume" "/Volumes/$nas_volume"
}

# create users.sls templates
function maketemplate() {
  for i in $(echo "${onboards}"); do \
cat <<- EOF
- name: $(echo "$i" | sed 's/@.*//' | tr -d '.' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
  email: $i
  disable: false
  sudo: false
  ssh_keys: '$(grep -i --colour "$i" "/Volumes/$nas_volume/$ssh_keys_file")'
    -
  roles:
    {{ role starts here }}
EOF
echo
done
}

# Ensure no empty arguments
#if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
#  echo "Yo dawg, I need some email addresses!" && usage
#fi

mountnas &>/dev/null
checkstat=$?

# if NAS mount succeeds then generate templates, unmount NAS and exit cleanly
[[ "$checkstat" -eq 0 ]] && \
  for i in "${onboards[@]}"; do
    maketemplate "$i"; 
  done && \

  umount "/Volumes/$nas_volume" && \
  (exit 0 || exit 1)
```

The idea is to be able to pass multiple addresses as arguments. If I invoke a `for` loop outside of the script such as `for i in $(cat emails); do ./get_sshkey.sh $i; done` this will create the templates from the here-doc function, but not like so:

`./mk_templates john@domain.com lisa@domain.com` it only works if I use a single address, not multiple.

Comment: Paste your script there and fix all bugs: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Thank you. I've fixed all the bugs reported on shellcheck.net. As the site advised, I changed `onboards="($@)"` to `onboards="($*)"`, but now when invoked the output is wrong.

```
- name: (johndoe
  email: (John.Doe@domain.com)
  disable: false
  sudo: false
  ssh_keys: ''
    -
  roles:
    {{ role starts here }}
```

Comment: I have onboards=("$*") which should expand as one long string, but I still only get the 1st email address returned when doing ./myscript "johndoe@domain.com mary@domain.com". I don't understand what I am really doing wrong.

Comment: Looks like I got the output working as expected. I needed to change the maketemplate function to use a for loop. I have updated the original code with what works.

Comment: slight simplification: `for i in ${onboards}; do ...` ; no quotes around `${onboards}` should allow each address to be handled as a separate item/token

Comment: When I removed the double quotes around ${onboards} suddenly the output was duplicated.

Comment: Ok, if I remove the for loop from the bottom of the script above the umount command then it outputs without duplication and no quotes around the 1st for loop. Thank you @markp